# Does 'Battery' matter to simulated pr2 robot

Tags: ros, battery, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that, when running pr2 in simulation for a long time, the battery will go down eventually to 0. Does that matter when there's no battery, if so, how to charge it?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10903/does-%27battery%27-matter-to-simulated-pr2-robot/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it does not matter.

---

Originally posted by [Tim Field](https://answers.ros.org/users/297/tim-field/) with karma: 191 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It tries to mimic [power_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/power_monitor) on the PR2, but has an additional subscription on ros topic `/gazebo/plugged_in` to change its own charge state (see [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins#gazebo_ros_power_node-1) for more details).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-15**:
yes, it worked, charging instantly to 100%... not sure what this field means  in "pr2_gazebo_plugins/PlugCommand.msg":  "float64 charge"